# How to calculate distance between highest value of function?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

[image]

Do you know if there is any algorithm or method for finding the distance between the highest points of a function, like that above (so the value of A, B, C, D and more)?

For example, when you have array of values of this function and array of arguments of this function.

Or maybe there is a built-in function in Python which does this?

```
y=np.array(radial)
x=np.arange(len(y))
m=argrelextrema(y, np.greater)[0]
z=[y[i] for i in m]



plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(m,z,'rs')
plt.show()
```

Where radial is a list of floats.

Comment: If you have a list of values, say v, it is relatively easy to find indices i with the property that v(i-1),  v(i+1)  < v(i) - which would make v(i) a local max -- but in your picture you are not simply computing the distances between successive local max but are ignoring some of them (the little spikes before the big spikes). You need to find a criteria that would distinguish between the little spikes which you don't want and the big ones which you do. Perhaps some sort of moving average will smooth the data to the point where it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`scipy.signal.argrelextrema`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) to find the index of the max values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

x = np.random.random(50) #data
m = argrelextrema(x, np.greater)[0] #array of indexes of the locals maxima
y = [x[i] for i in m] #array of max values

plot(x)
plot(m, y, 'rs')
show()
```

[image]

After finding the max values, you can use [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to find the distances:

```
distances = [np.linalg.norm(np.array([m[i], y[i-1]]) - np.array([m[i-1], y[i-1]])) for i in np.arange(1, len(m))]
```

Or just subtract:

```
distances = [m[i] - m[i-1] for i in np.arange(1, len(m))]
```

Or even just use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

```
distances = np.diff(m)
```

Adding this code for a nicer plot and test the result:

```
for i in range(len(distances)):
    plot([m[i], m[i] + distances[i]], 2*[y[i]], color = 'g')
    axvline(m[i], linestyle='--', color='0.75')
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful,but I have problem with finding index of max value.I have did excactly like you but my plot mark only 2 max value.Mayby you know why?

Comment: can you post the source of your data? so I can see what could be the problem.

Comment: Well... That should have worked... Is the radial list containing the values you expect?

Comment: Ok I know why i have this problem.Becouse some of my max value are repeating.If you look closly at my chart you will see that most of my tops are flat.

Comment: look the image for this data: `data = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x%2 else 2, list(range(50)))))` http://s10.postimg.org/p2m80woh5/flat.png , worked fine.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this       data = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x%2 else 2, list(range(50))))) Could you explain me how to fix my problem?

Comment: this data is just a list [1,2,1,2,1,2...]  where the max values is always the same: 2.

Comment: But I really dont know what is going on with your case. Can you post a little range of your y?

Comment: Back and thought something... but solving your problem would be another question. What you would need to do is take the `argrelextrema` not with `np.greater`, but with `np.greater_equal`. But now, by the fact you're getting equal points too, not desired points will appear. To rid of them, first you need to clear from the list you got the points that are repeating. After this clean, you take a new `argrextrema`, but now with `np.greater`. That's gonna result in the peaks you want.